# magento 2.3 Design Configuration > Global page keep loading

Tags: configuration, magento2.3.0

I'm using `magento 2.3 ver`, i getting some issue about `Design Configuration` > `Global` > `page` keep loading. but `Main Website` and `Main Website Store` is working.

i already `rm -rf generated/code var/* pub/static/` and then `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` but no luck.

This is Global page message. please help, thank you!

```
file-uploader.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Base64 is not defined
    at UiClass.processFile (file-uploader.min.js:1)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at UiClass.setInitialValue (file-uploader.min.js:1)
    at UiClass.initialize (abstract.min.js:1)
    at UiClass.initialize (wrapper.min.js:3)
    at new UiClass (class.min.js:3)
    at Object.initComponent (layout.min.js:8)
    at fire (jquery.min.js:212)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:218)
    at Object.deferred.(/index.php/admin/theme/design_config/edit/scope/default/key/3d098cdba6b78b5b34afeb20d3e1f3d052972a2b3b29bc3d63761/anonymous function) (http://www.domain.com/pub/static/version154399332/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.min.js:220:56)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just follow this

Open those files

```
> /vendor/magento/module-email/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml
> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml
> /vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml
> /vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml
> /vendor/magento/module-theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml
```

search for

```
formElement="fileUploader"
```

replace with

```
formElement="imageUploader"
```

in all files

clear cache and reload.

Comment: works for me! I edited core and i liked it!

Comment: @Vvvaida can we override this in our theme ?(without edited core files)

Answer (score 0):

You can check fix for this in:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19549

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/18851/commits/ba69bfec127bed8c39c7d9e7b73d10b54449b158