# Magento 2 : base 64 is not defined error in image upload in admin grid

Tags: magento2, custom-admin-grid

I want to upload an image from admin grid after selecting the image rounds goes loading and console **base64** is not defined is coming.

screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of looks like the problem [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252416/magento-2-3-design-configuration-global-page-keep-loading):

If you're on Magento 2.3 I'd recommend making the changes given in the approved answer.